# How to show images in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an image column in a database table, and I want to show this image in a GridView column, how can I implement that?

Comment: do you have any problem with msdn link "GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Displaying Images in a GridView Column" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

Comment: @volody - this link depend on the database image filed is string but in my database is varbinary(MAX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what @JaneDoe suggest, you'll need to specify the ImageUrl, however when you bind, you'll need to set the ImageUrl property to point to an HttpHandler with the primary key as a query string parameter.

e.g. `<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="/myImageHandler.axd?pk=<%# Eval("PrimaryKey") %>"/>`

You'll then need to configure your HttpHandler to send a response of image/jpeg or whatever image type you're storing and then read the varbinary data from the DB based on the PK passed in, in the query string and output that data to the response stream.

Comment: yes i did it through the Handler, thannks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you saved the image in your database as a string (path to the image) you can just put an itemtemplate in your gridview like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:image ID="image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "imagePath") %>'  />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: i don't understand "imagePath", the image from database.

Comment: do you store your image as a string in your database? and if so: what is the name of the column in which you store your images ? also, how do you bind your data to the gridview?

Comment: +1 @Gandhi - ImagePath is the path to the image.  It could be called anything its just a column name - use what you have.

Comment: @JaneDoe - the column of image is varbinary(MAX), not like you said string.

Comment: in that case i wouldn't know how to get the images in your gridview. I suggest you to save images as a string tho, it's way more space efficient and easier to work with.

Comment: @JaneDoe - thanks i know that but i have to save all images in my database.

Comment: @Gandhi are you obligated to save them in binary ? else you could just save the picture in your database like this "/mypics/pic1.jpg". (this is merely an example ofcourse)